# React файл index.css с таким же содержимым как и index.html

Tags: html, css, reactjs

Столкнулся с такой проблемой, что подключая любой `css` файл в `index.html`, на самом сайте подключается этот `css` файл, но с содержимым таким же как `index.html`

Код:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <title>React App</title>
    <link href="./index.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Вот так выглядит эта проблема, причем с любым `css` файлом.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код App.js, я убрал весь код который был у меня, но проблема осталась.

```
function App() {
  return (<div></div>)
}

export default App;
```

Comment: А вопрос ваш в чем? приведенный код - никак не влияет на подгрузку css

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков в том, как решить эту проблему. Скажите, что нужно выложить, я выложу. Приведенный код показывает, что я подключаю `index.css`, а скриншот показывает, что да был подгружен `index.css`, но его содержимое как `index.html`.

Comment: Скиньте код src/App.Js. Есть подозрения что вы меняете\подключаете файлы в файле public/index.html

Сам файл стиля подключаете в компоненте или на обрабатываемой странице сайта, а далее при помощи команды npm run build (или) yarn build собирается в файл index.css.

Comment: @YuraLons выложил код, проблема как я понимаю не в коде, по крайней мере не в `App.js` т.к. я из него все убрал и проблема осталась.

Comment: @YuraLons удалил вообще все что было и `App.js`, и `node_modules` и `package-lock`. `index.js` у меня стандартный, все стандартное осталось. Использовал команду `npm install`, а потом `npm start` и проблема та же. Наверно проще уже пересоздать проект...

Comment: В файл App.js подключите просто ваш файл стилей ( `import './index.css';` )

Comment: @YuraLons да, это работает конечно, но теперь интересно понять почему все поломалось. Т.к. до этого у меня `index.css` лежал в `public` и подключался напрямую в `html` файле и все прекрасно работало, вот даже создал новый проект и сделал все так же и все работает правильно. Но ладно, спасибо за помощь!